# python3 websocket server blocks script

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I have a headless linux system that I want to control/get stats through a web page.  I did this in the past (python2?) on a different system that is no longer with us. It worked even without the Threaded run_forever.   Now with python3 the script is blocked (doesn't continue) past server.run_forever.  The server runs fine and communicates with the webpage, but the data collection doesn't run until the server is  c.   I am commanding this through  putty ssh.   The webserver and webpage code is not included below.

How do I get a running socket server and server side interactions?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/willi/shared/lib")
from threading import Thread
from websocket_server import WebsocketServer 
import os
import time
import subprocess
from  compass.compass import compass
from  webserv.wifiscan import wifiSigLevel
from  accelerometer.inclin import inclin

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

class potatoSetup():
    compass = ""
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def run_command(self, cmd):
        with semaphore:
            subprocess.Popen(cmd) 
            os.system(cmd)
    def setupI2c(self):
        i2c = os.system("i2cdetect -y 1")
        if i2c !="0" :
           i2c =  os.system("sudo ldto enable i2c-b")
    def runServer(self):    
        PORT = 9001
        HOST = '192.168.1.245'
        global server
        try:
            server = WebsocketServer(PORT,HOST)
            thread = Thread(target=server.run_forever(),daemon=True)
        except Exception as err :
            print("oops server fail %s" % err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tade = potatoSetup()
    tade.setupI2c()
    direction = compass()
    pitchRoll = inclin(0x68)
    wsl = wifiSigLevel("webserv/") 
    tade.runServer()  
    angle_xz, angle_yz = pitchRoll.get_inclination()
    print("XZ angle = {:6.2f}deg   YZ angle = {:6.2f}deg".format(angle_xz, angle_yz))
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("\rHeading: {0}    ".format( direction.getDirection()))
        angle_xz, angle_yz = pitchRoll.get_inclination()
        sys.stdout.write("Pitch = {:6.2f}deg   Roll = {:6.2f}deg".format(angle_xz, angle_yz))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I have search the internut for dayz and tried lots of the things...

Comment: The solution I am going with is to make a stand alone server script and put a client in my server side data collection script.  That way the web client and the server side client can exchange data.  The "server" is just a relay

Comment: NEXT,  I find clients do the same, seems run_forever() does what it says.  So don't use it.  I am now using self.ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://192.168.1.245:9001") to establish communication with the server.    (ws is a class variable)  then  self.ws.send(messages) work anywhere. I have a while True loop that does data collection and has a self.ws.recv() statement.